# .NET. Mail not sent any attached files with two step verification on office 365

Tags: .net, azure, json.net, nuget

I send emails without problem using this .Net program, but if I attach a file it never arrives.
In the mail server appears that the mail has arrived correctly, but that it does not include any attachment.
On the other hand, if with the same configuration I send an email with an attachment using PoweShell, the attachment arrives without a problem.
Thanks

`````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private string tenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private string to = "tothisemail@gmail.com";
        private string subject = "Test Email";
        private string body = "This is a test email sent from C# Windows Forms using Microsoft Graph API";
        private string token;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void SendEmailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                token = await GetAccessToken();

                var email = new
                {
                    saveToSentItems = false,
                    message = new
                    {
                        subject = subject,
                        body = new
                        {
                            contentType = "Text",
                            content = body
                        },
                        toRecipients = new[]
                        {
                            new
                            {
                                emailAddress = new
                                {
                                    address = to
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    attachments = new[]
                    {
                        new
                            {
                                odataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                                name = "Hello.pdf",
                                contentBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\temp\Hello.pdf"))
                            }
                    }
                };

                var emailJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(email);
                await SendEmail(emailJson);
                MessageBox.Show("Email sent successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error sending email: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
                var tokenEndpoint = $"{authority}/oauth2/token";

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com")
                });

                var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, content);
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    dynamic jsonResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent);
                    return jsonResponse.access_token;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to obtain access token.");
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task SendEmail(string emailJson)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                var uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/fromthisemail@nnnnn.com/sendMail";
                var content = new StringContent(emailJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                try
                {
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Failed to send the email.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error sending email: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}````
`````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the Microsoft Graph API to send an email from a C# Windows Forms application, and you are trying to attach a file to the email.

I have tried code from my end and I am able to send mail.

Ensure that the file path is correct. In your code, you're attaching a file located at `@"c:\temp\Hello.pdf"`.
Make sure that the file exists at that location and that the application has the necessary permissions to access the file.
Check the required scopes and permissions for sending emails with attachments using Microsoft Graph API. You might need to update the application registration to include the `Mail.Send` permission.

[image]

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string clientId = "clientId";
        private string clientSecret = "clientSecret";
        private string tenantId = "tenantId";
        private string to = "to mail";
        private string from = "from mail";
        private string token;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void SendEmailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Step 1: Obtain Access Token
                token = await GetAccessToken();

                // Step 2: Prepare Email JSON Payload
                var email = PrepareEmailJson();

                // Step 3: Send Email
                await SendEmail(email);

                MessageBox.Show("Email sent successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error sending email: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }


        private async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
                var tokenEndpoint = $"{authority}/oauth2/token";

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com")
                });

                var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, content);
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    dynamic jsonResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent);
                    return jsonResponse.access_token;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to obtain access token.");
                }
            }
        }

        private string PrepareEmailJson()
        {
            // Step 2: Prepare Email JSON Payload
            var email = new
            {
                saveToSentItems = false,
                message = new
                {
                    subject = subject,
                    body = new
                    {
                        contentType = "Text",
                        content = body
                    },
                    toRecipients = new[]
                    {
                        new
                        {
                            emailAddress = new
                            {
                                address = to
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                attachments = new[]
                {
                    new
                    {
                        odataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                        name = "YourFileName",
                        contentBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"PathofYourFile")),
                        contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
                    }
                }
            };    
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(email);
        }

        private async Task SendEmail(string emailJson)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                var uri = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{from}/sendMail";
                var content = new StringContent(emailJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                try
                {
                    // Step 3: Send Email
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Failed to send the email.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error sending email: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Hello. 
I've found that both codes send the mail, but both without an attachment. 
Also checked that there is the app permission to send emails with attachments using Microsoft Graph API (from PowerShell I have no problem) and Mail.Send
But he still doesn't send the attachment, only the email.
Thank you

Comment: Hello. I still haven't found the reason why it's not sending the attachments... any ideas?